# How can I use text objects to select lines between braces?

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to select lines inside two braces, but not the lines with the braces themselves. For example, in the following Sass code:

```
#main {
  h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

If I put the cursor on line 3 and type `vi{`, it selects the whitespace before the closing `}`. How can I only select lines *between* braces?

Comment: Interestingly enough, for me, whether I use vi{ or Vi{ it only selects lines 3 and 4, but does not select the white space on line 5. So, not sure why it is working for me, but not for you.

Comment: He must be having a empty character which get selected.

Comment: What version of Vim do you use? On what system?